# Many to many one to one relationship SSAS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, ssis-2012, msbi

Guys I am working on a Cube, AS i am just a fresher in developing the SSAS cube so that I am facing some problems .

What is junction table in many to many relationship .
&
I am having a doubt too 
While defining relationship i felt like the relationship use to work like joins either it is many to many  (One or more columns comparison b/w the tables)or one to one(only one column comparison b/w the tables). Am I right or not

Thanks in advance  :)

Answer (score 1):

A junction table in a many to many relationship would hold the 2 keys from each table and allow each table to be related to each other through this table.

Typically a one to one relationship would involve 2 tables and a many to many 3.

There is a great explanation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170463.aspx)